# American English or British English Java

Tags: java, spelling

I have a question about language in Java. I've tried googling for an answer, but although I found a related question regarding personal preference, the *technical* side wasn't really addressed. So this is it-

Does it matter *to Java* if you use British English or American English? Does it cause any complications technically speaking if you use British English (as long as your code is written consistently)?

I'm Australian and proud of the Britishness of our language so this is relevant to me.

Comment: You mean in the actual code itself?

Comment: java will understand only its syntax, neither American, nor British.

Comment: Can you give an example of a British English statement/idiom that should be in the code? And I presume you are not discussing localization of Strings.

Comment: I don't know British English very well, but I think that java was designed with American English in mind (color instead of colour). But I would just go into an ide and check out what errors it will throw. As long as you stop thinking about it in terms of American vs British and just think of the language as "java" I think you will be fine

Comment: It doesn't matter on the code side, on the localization side it's compatible with both. You should give us a clear example of what you have in mind ?

Comment: As long as you're compliant with grammar and syntax of `Java` language. It doesn't matter which language you use.

Comment: I think the language was original written in "Huttese", and got its name from his original creator Jabba from Tatooine

Comment: @MarkE I thought it was named after those little hoody people - the javas ...

Comment: @Fildor you've got a common misinformation. They are called Jawas, and they created C#. Although they're all from Tatooine, hence the strong typing. The dessert makes you wanna be sure of what you're talking about.

Comment: If you're using a library class like [`Color`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html), you have to spell the identifiers the same way they're defined.  In fact, if you're using someone else's library and they've misspelt an identifier, you have to misspell it the exact same way when you use it.

Comment: @MarkE Oh, my bad. I also heard, they were the inventors of "Sandboxing" ... haha

Comment: Don't know what all the close-votes are for on this question — it's neither unclear nor opinion-based.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8) says:

"*An identifier is an unlimited-length sequence of Java letters and Java digits, the first of which must be a Java letter.*"

You write code in Java, not in English, German or Chinese. Java doesn't care if your "identifiers" (package-names, class-names, variable-names,, method-names etc.) are a real word at all, if you look at obfuscated code, you'll see class-names like "A" and method-names like "x". Since Java supports Unicode, you could use non-ascii letters like 'ö' or even Chinese signs.

[Java-Keywords](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-Keyword) (`public`, `protected`, `while` etc. and `true`, `false` and `null` of course) are fixed, you have to write them the way the Specification says.

Answer (score 3):

The ultimate goal of any code (Java or not) to be easy readable. You should not use terms that others can't clearly understand (domain-specific terms are exception). So choose not between British and American, but between less and more clear.